# A pig or a core

Tags: word-meaning

At https://science.slashdot.org/comments.pl?sid=14838212&cid=59217186 I read this sentence

> Insulin back then was obtained by grinding up a pancreas of a pig or a
>   core and purifying the insulin contained in it.

What is a *core* in this context? I looked it up on Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core but the only entry under biology was *Core (anatomy), everything except the appendages*.

I can't imagine it is a misspelling (Of what, dog? Cow?)

Comment: IMO, it's a misspelling of a **crow**

Comment: Don't expect good, pure, error-free English from Slashdot! From the articles, and especially not from the comments.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is based on a typo and should not be left open and get bumped from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

Reading in context it is surely an auto-correction error for "cow".   Pigs and cows are both common large farm animals and I suppose either would be suitable for insulin production.

Moreover, the letters E and R are next to W on the keyboard, so typing "A PIG OR COE", could be autocorrected to "... CORE".

It would have been easy to correct, but people don't tend to worry about typos on internet forums like slashdot.